# Add remove button on jQuery UI autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

How I can add remove button on jQuery UI autocomplete items?
I am populating the items like this.

```
    $('#item-options').autocomplete({
        source: (req, res) => {
            let r = $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                itemOptionItems,
                req.term
            );

            res(r.slice(0, 10));
        },
        close: (event, ui) => {
            $('#item-options').trigger(cm.enterEvent());
        }
    });
```

I  am trying to accomplish similar like this.

[image]

This is a screenshot from my old winform app.

I will appreciate any  advice/help will come, thanks.

Comment: do you want to remove the autocomplete items or autocomplete itself

Comment: @user3040610 just the  items  only. Something like if  the user click the x button then that item will be remove.